# Access mobile phone memory in a device independent way?

Tags: mobile, mobile-phones

I have the requirement to access the following data, where available, on mobile phones with a device independent code

Needed data is

- Contacts
- Phone logs
- Appointments
- Tasks
- Voice notes and recordings SMS messages
- Pictures Videos Application Data
- Email and Email attachments

This is needed to write a sort of cleanup application

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it ain't as easy as that. You have to specify which phone models you are interested in. There is not "Device independent" way of doing this across brands.
Sorry.